# PHP: cookies via path/domain

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Is it possible to set the path and domain one time at the beginning of the script and have all future sets conform to the same?

From the docs:

```
 bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

Comment: write a function to do it

Comment: @Dagon. Please explain.  How will this allow setcookie() to use these domains/paths every time it is called?

Comment: just as Jon says, and remember you don't have to set all those values, some of the defaults may be what you want in the first instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure:

```
function own_setcookie($name, $value, $expire=0) {
    setcookie($name, $value , $expire, 'myPath', 'myDomain');
}
```

then use:

```
own_setcookie('myName', 'myValue');
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand Dagon's comment.  Makes sense.  Do you typically use this approach, or are you just addressing my question?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I actually use a cookie handler class that I created, but it does function along the same lines of defaulting values like this function does. ^^